# Compiled python code Vs py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I have used PyScripter to generate *compiled python code* file in a project. If I could generate such files using IDE's what is the need of Py2Exe?

I can run my applications using compiled python code..

Answer (score 0):

I have not used PyScripter myself but looking at their website. I can at-least find three reasons

1. "If you are using a 64bit version of Windows note that PyScripter will only work if a 32bit version of Python is installed" as quoted [here](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/).
2. [Compatibility with Python 2.7](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/wiki/FAQ#Which_Python_versions_are_supported?)
3. [Running on my Linux Box. I am not a great fan of Wine](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_use_PyScripter_in_Ubuntu)